# Can I say "unveil something ajar?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I will understand if you think this phrase doesn't make sense and probably make you cringe. If you ask me, this is my way to learn some new words i.e. making sentences even if they will sound awkward. I'm trying to make a figurative sentence by the way. Here is the sentence:

> I don't always open up to someone, as if I wrapped myself up with a
> thick cover, but I can possibly **unveil them ajar** just in case one
> cares.

Comment: The problem is that unveiling means remove the veil; ajar means slightly open. Your two main words are at odds. Also, you're not unveiling them -- you'd be unveiling yourself.

Comment: @FeliniusRex when I was constructing this sentence, I thought of a big house made of cloth(?) and I let the door open ajar though it's not literally a door. Something like a tent. I was trying to say like that, but I could sense that from my sentence above doesn't go well.

Comment: I hear you, and I salute your efforts. There's been lots of sentences where I tried things and it didn't work out either, but I understand what you're aiming at. Maybe try something like moving the curtain aside, because that gives just a glimpse of what lies beyond.

Comment: *Ajar* is really only ever used with doors, so it sounds very strange to say that anything else is ajar.

Comment: This is a request for proofreading, and so is off-topic

Comment: @gotube No it is not. I'm asking whether I can use this word like that way. People on this site always force posters to give examples every time asking a question as an attempt. That's why I'm making this sentence. You wouldn't find this sentence anywhere. And I have spent a long time just to construct this sentence and somenone closing this question? How nice! Well, smart people often discourage a stupid learner like me to learn more by closing a trivial question like this. What's the use of the tags "word usage" and "sentence-construction" if I'm not allowed to ask a question like this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133909/discussion-on-question-by-user516076-can-i-say-unveil-something-ajar).

Comment: @user516076 I've tried to answer your questions in the chat, so please have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unveil loosely means to "reveal." Ajar means "open."  These words are slightly similar in their reference to allowing someone or something (like feelings) to be seen.
However, they are not clearly used in the sentence you've posted. You must also specify the pronoun "them". What is the antecedent this word is replacing?
Try "I can occasionally unveil my feelings in case anyone/someone cares."  OR "I can occasionally leave my feelings ajar..."
I believe "feelings/emotions" is the antecedent that refers to "them."

I don't have a reference for my answer. I teach writing classes and grade a lot of essays!